# _utime() on Windows is not working with a specified time in C program

Tags: c, windows, winapi, time

`_utime` with NULL as a time parameter is updating given file's modification time but when I set time to other value as shown in the example it does not affect and it is giving error as "Invalid argument", please let me know how to use it.

Following is the sample program I want to make it work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <warning.h>>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/utime.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void main (void) {    
    struct _utimbuf updatedtime;
    char *file_path = "file_name.txt";
    int ret;

    // here _utime update the modification time to the current time.
    ret = _utime(file_path, NULL);
    if(ret == -1)
        printf("ret: %d \t GetLastError: %d \t strerror: %s\n", ret, errno, strerror(errno));

    updatedtime.modtime = time(0) - 100000;
    // here, _utime has no effect on the time.
    ret = _utime(file_path, &updatedtime);
    if(ret == -1)
        printf("ret: %d \t GetLastError: %d \t strerror: %s\n", ret, errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the code in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/utime-utime32-utime64-wutime-wutime32-wutime64?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: `mtime` is not defined in the code segment you have included.

Comment: @Mgetz,  Yes I tried just now, I found that to change the file modification time with _utime() we need to give valid values in both of the fields of the structure _utimbuf, I was only changing the modification time and access time was an invalid value.

Comment: @not_a_real_confucius then post that as the answer

Comment: @ryyker thanks for pointing it out, I have modified the example.

Answer (score 1):

As referred in [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/utime-utime32-utime64-wutime-wutime32-wutime64?view=vs-2019) for changing the file modification time with _utime() we need to give valid values in both of the fields of the structure _utimbuf, In the example given in the question, It was only changing the modification time and access time was an invalid value.

The following code is working as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/utime.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void main (void) {    
    struct _utimbuf updatedtime;
    char *file_path = "C:\\Users\\test_dir\\file_name.txt";
    char sys_cmd[100];
    int ret;

    sprintf(sys_cmd, "dir %s", file_path);

    ret = _utime(file_path, NULL);
    if(ret == -1)
       printf("GetLastError: %d \t strerror: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));

    updatedtime.modtime = time(0) - 100000;
    updatedtime.actime = time(0);
    
    system(sys_cmd);
    ret = _utime(file_path, &updatedtime);
    if(ret == -1)
       printf("GetLastError: %d \t strerror: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    system(sys_cmd);
}
```

output:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 10FD-414D

 Directory of C:\Users\test_dir

09-08-2020  15:24               158 file_name.txt
               1 File(s)            158 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  59,508,273,152 bytes free
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 10FD-414D

 Directory of C:\Users\test_dir

10-08-2020  19:11               158 file_name.txt
               1 File(s)            158 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  59,508,273,152 bytes free
```

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.